# Invalid rank identifier

Tags: c#, syntax, multidimensional-array

I'm currently translating my java game engine to c#. This is my array mapdata

```````````
char[][] mapdata = new char[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
                                       ``````````
```````````

It shows this error.

> > Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' (CS0178) - C:\Users\sriharshachilakapati...ne\Map.cs:74,39

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays are written this way:

```
char[,] mapdata = new char[width, height];
```

`char[][]` is a array in a array, used this way:

```
char[][] mapdata = new char[width][];
for (int i = 0; i < mapdata.Length; i++)
{
    mapdata[i] = new char[height];
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I think it's a major syntax difference between c# and java

Answer (score 2):

You are try to define a *[`multidimensional array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)*. Here is how in C#;

```
char[,] mapdata = new char[MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT];
```

From [*`Compiler Error CS0178`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ax0bze%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> An array initialization was ill-formed. When specifying the array
>   dimensions, you can specify the following:
>
> - A number in brackets
> - Empty brackets
> - A comma enclosed in brackets

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize subranks of a jagged array at compile time.

You have to do it like this:

```
char[][] mapdata = new char[MAP_WIDTH][];

for (int = 0; i < mapdata.Length; ++i)
    mapdata[i]= new char[MAP_HEIGHT];
```

Or you could instead use a multidimensional array:

```
char[,] mapdata = new char[MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT];
```